# Does it make sense to make my own DNA copy (kind of backup) while I am young?

Tags: dna, dna-damage

As I understand, when I am getting older DNA becomes more and more damaged in my body.

Does it make sense to make my own DNA copy (kind of backup) while I am young (38 years old or for my kids) in case that in future there will be the technology which will make possible to restore damaged DNA from this copy and make me younger?

Or it does not make sense, because original not damaged DNA always can be found in some places of my body?

If it makes sense, what is the best way to do this DNA backup? Cut a piece of hair or nails or freeze a piece of saliva?

Answer (score 3):

While your DNA gets damaged, not every single cell will have the same damage.  Your consensus DNA sequence will not change.

Comment: I still did not get from your answer if it make sense to make DNA backup or not.

Answer (score -2):

No, it does not make sense. When you ask: "in future there will be the technology which will make possible to restore damaged DNA from this copy and make me younger?" I can confidently say that there won't be such technology, for the following reasons.

1) DNA is only one component of your body's cells; important of course, but not really the 'master regulator' of everything about you (in fact, practically all cellular functions are performed by proteins and other molecules, not DNA). This belief (that DNA can determine every aspect of life) is called '[genetic determinism](https://tannerlectures.utah.edu/_documents/a-to-z/l/lewontin83.pdf)', and it is known to not hold even in trivial cases.

2) Your environment (diet, air, sun, family, friends, society, random events) plays a major role in who you are and *how you age*. Even if you were to repair all DNA damage as soon as it occurred (which, by the way, your cells do quite efficiently anyway), you could still not control for all there is outside of you, and thence you could not really 'rejuvenate' with the magic DNA pill. Most people tend to ignore this when fantasizing about DNA's healing powers: *there is a world outside*.

3) DNA is not something you drink or take as a 'medicine', not now, not in the future. The technology needed to rejuvenate all of your cells will likely not include 'DNA repair'. It might have to do more with metabolism than anything else (also, mutations occur all the time and not all of them are bad, so in fact 'repairing' DNA with your 'juvenile' DNA might not even be good long term).

4) It *might* make sense to freeze some of your cells for other applications (like tissue regeneration for you/your children), but it is quite expensive at the moment and usually requires a sample of your umbilical cord. I presume the technology to de-differentiate adult cells to totipotential cells is quite feasible, so in the future this application might be accessible, buy still unrelated to rejuvenation (unless there is something like 'whole body' tissue replacement).

As for the previous answer, "Your consensus DNA sequence will not change" makes no scientific sense. Your DNA sequences (of all of your cells) change all the time, and there is no 'average', or 'consensus' inside of you (the term consensus is simply a convention used in molecular biology for simplification).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let's think that theoretically there will be technology to recover DNA. In this assumption does it make sense to make DNA backup or original not damaged DNA always can be found somewhere in the body?